# is there any way to customize the shopify checkout page based on customer tags?

Tags: shopify

so far the only liquid variable I've found defined is settings. shop, customer, and order are all not defined, which is disappointing.

Is there any way to hide/show elements based on what tags a customer has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the two checkout pages where the customer inputs their information, then no.  I believe nothing 3rd party can run on there for security reasons and whatnot.

I'm quite certain that you can only change the stylesheet for the checkout pages.